# Issue with setInterval() not accessing directive function in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, scope, settimeout, angular2-directives

I'm trying to make a news ticker directive that slides the element across its parent so that you can read the string if it's too long. I'm stuck because I can't get the `setInterval()` function to call the `moveLeft()` function in its current scope, and thereby move the target element (`this.node1`) over by `1px`. If I pass the element, function, and parameters into the `setInterval()` then the the DOM isn't adjusted, because I think the element is out of scope. **How can I call the `moveLeft()` function in its current scope from a `setInterval()` function?** The function works fine when called outside of the `setInterval()` function.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[ticker]' })
export class TickerDirective implements OnInit {

    currMargin: number;             // i.e.: 4
    newMargin: string;              // i.e.: '4px'
    currInterval: any;              // timeout function variable used to kill the timeout

    container: any;                 // container element
    node1: any;
    node2: any;
    tickerNodes: any[];

    textValue: string;
    @Input('text') text: string;    // display string passed in on an attribute

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {  }

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        // this is where the script is failing
        this.currInterval = setInterval( this.moveLeft(), 100);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        clearInterval(this.currInterval);
        this.currMargin = 0;
    }

    moveLeft() { // slide the elements to the left
        this.currMargin -= 1;
        this.newMargin = this.currMargin + 'px';
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.node1, 'margin-left', this.newMargin);
    }

    ngOnInit() { // instantiate the elements
        this.currMargin = 0;
        this.textValue = this.el.nativeElement.attributes[2].nodeValue; // sets the text value passed from the component to the directive through an attribute

        // build the container
        this.container = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement, 'div');
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.container, 'ticker-container', true);

        // create the left most element
        this.node1 = this.renderer.createElement(this.container, 'div');
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.node1, 'ticker-node', true);
        this.renderer.setText(this.node1, this.el.nativeElement.attributes[2].nodeValue);

        // create the right most element
        this.node2 = this.renderer.createElement(this.container, 'div');
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.node2, 'ticker-node', true);
        this.renderer.setText(this.node2, this.el.nativeElement.attributes[2].nodeValue);

        // render the elementss
        this.tickerNodes = [this.node1, this.node2];
        this.renderer.attachViewAfter(this.container, this.tickerNodes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` inside the method you call

```
moveLeft() { // slide the elements to the left
    setInterval(() => {
            this.currMargin -= 1;
            this.newMargin = this.currMargin + 'px';
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.node1, 'margin-left', this.newMargin);
    }, 100);    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, in your original, you are executing moveleft during your interval setup, instead of providing the function. So it will get executed when you set it up, but never again.

ie. `setInterval( this.moveLeft, 100)` instead of `setInterval( this.moveLeft(), 100)`

But the real issue is to provide an arrow function to the setInterval, instead of the function directly, as simply giving it the function will change the context of `this` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

eg. `setInterval( () => { this.moveLeft(); }, 100)`